# How to find the best line Fit Python(banister-impulse model)

Tags: python, linear-regression

I have this formula that is used to predict athletic performance base on daily stress.
It is based on 5 constant unique to each person. I'm trying to find these based on daily stress and performance testing that has been done. I'm new to programming and I don't know where to start. 
[see the formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Llzg3.png)

Performance= Fitness(=daily stress+yesterday fitness put decay) - Fatigue(daily stress+yesterday fatigue put decay) +P0
This is a sample of the data: [data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vcF4.png%60)

thank you

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math
from scipy import optimize

data = pd.read_csv('data_mod1.csv')

TSS = data['stress'].fillna(0)
arr = np.array(TSS) 
#data = data.dropna()

a = [arr[0]]
b = [arr[0]]
x = arr[1:]

def Banister(x, t1, t2,k1,k2, c):
    for v in x: 
        a.append(a[-1]*np.exp(-1/t1) + v)
        b.append(b[-1]*np.exp(-1/t2) + v)
        data['fit'] = pd.Series(a)
        data['fat'] = pd.Series(b)
        data['perf'] = ((data['fit']*k1)-(data['fat']*k2))+c
    return data['perf'] 


# In[ ]:


from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
fit = curve_fit(Banister, arr,data[data.index], p0=[20, 10,1 ,2, 50])
```

Comment: Are you requesting a complete brand new code from zero or did you already tried to code something ? If you've already tried something, you should post it in a block of code in your question, it'll be easier to answer if we can see what you've tried to do ! ^^

Comment: thanks, i've made changes to the question

Comment: I'm able to get k1,k2 and c, but curve_fit keeps the same inital value for t1 and t2. Also  , I have this problem where my performance has not a value for everyday so i need to average it out but I would like to just fit the function to the point I have. I don't know how to do that since by indepedent variable is daily stress and I can't do .dropna

Comment: I don't know all packages you're using so I can't help you with them, but when I read the doc, I see that int `curve_fit`, `p0` argument is an array representing parameters of given method `f`, but here, `f = Banister`, and `Banister` takes 6 arguments, but `p0` contains only 5, maybe you should check that. I'm sorry but I can't help anymore.